# prevent content hidden with ng-hide from rendering on the page briefly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm somewhat new to angular and have a question about an element that briefly renders on the page before disappearing. I would like to stop this behavior but I'm not sure how.

I have a radio button with the ng-model="Download" and ng-value="3". Then there is a div form that has ng-hide="Download !=3". This effectively means that the form stays hidden unless someone clicks the radio button. However it appears as though it renders the form first before applying the ng-hide logic.

Any ideas on how to tackle this so this form stays hidden unless the radio button is selected, instead of rendering for a split moment?

Comment: Can you use `style="display: none;"` in the html and then remove that in the javascript onload function?

Answer (score 2):

You could try an approach with the directive [ng-cloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak), please, ensure that you have a proper css rule for hiding html code by default:

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
    display: none !important;
}
```